# Scala mapping and reducing to an Array

Tags: arrays, string, scala, dictionary, reduce

I have the following format on my data

```
{sentenceA1}{tab}{sentenceB1}  
{sentenceA2}{tab}{sentenceB1}  
{sentenceA3}{tab}{sentenceB2}  
{sentenceA4}{tab}{sentenceB2}
```

and I want to get the array of sentencesA that match to B using Scala

```
[sentenceA1, sentenceA2]  
[sentenceA3, sentenceA4]
```

I tried the following

`val file1 = file.map(line => line.split("\t"))`
`val file2 = file1.map(line => (line(1), line(0)))`
`file2.reduceLeft(_+_).collect`

but its not successful

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
list.map(line => line.split("\t")).
    map(a => a(1) -> a(0)).
    groupBy(_._1).
    mapValues(_.map(_._2))
```

Or

```
list.map(line => line.split("\t")).
    groupBy(_(1)).
    mapValues(_.map(_(0)))
```

And you'll get a map

```
{SentenceB1} -> {sentenceA1, sentenceA2}
{SentenceB2} -> {sentenceA3, sentenceA4}
```

Comment: just an extension. If i wanted to do a maping this way
{SentenceA1} -> {SentenceA2}
{SentenceA2} -> {SentenceA1} etc
do you have any suggestions?

Comment: If I understood you correctly, you want to have collection {sentenceA1 -> sentenceA2} {sentanseA3 -> sentanceA4}. In this case you can add .map({case (k, list) => list(0) -> list(1)}) to the end of any construction, but this would suggest, that you always have a pair in your sequence.

Comment: to be more specific, i want to map sentenceA1 to every sentenceA that have some sentenceB in common.

Comment: I posted it in a different question for better insight
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26701902/map-one-value-to-all-values-with-a-common-relation-scala

Answer (score 1):

Read your lines from datasource (I use predefined list to simplify example):

```
val lines = List(
  "sentenceA1\tsentenceB1",
  "sentenceA2\tsentenceB1",
  "sentenceA3\tsentenceB2",
  "sentenceA4\tsentenceB2"
)
```

Process each line:

- split by tab symbol.
- group by second token
- simplify grouped values by skipping second line token.

Code looks like this:

```
val result = lines
  .map(_.split("\t"))
  .groupBy(_(1))
  .mapValues( _.map(_(0)))
```

Comment: I tried it and I added a   .foreach(println)
to see the output but did not work

Comment: Yes, it's ok. You're able to consume it how you want.

Answer (score 0):

Consider also a container class

```
case class Text(s:String) {
  val Array(a,b,_*) = s.split("\t") 
}
```

that splits each element in `List[String]`; thus

```
for ( (k,xs) <- lines.map(Text(_)).groupBy(_.b) ) yield k -> xs.map(_.a)
```

delivers the desired association.