# Map one value to all values with a common relation Scala

Tags: scala, dictionary, group-by, reduce

Having a set of data:

```
{sentenceA1}{\t}{sentenceB1}  
{sentenceA1}{\t}{sentenceB2}  
{sentenceA2}{\t}{sentenceB1}   
{sentenceA3}{\t}{sentenceB1}   
{sentenceA4}{\t}{sentenceB2}
```

I want to map a sentenceA to all the sentences that have a common sentenceB in Scala so the result will be something like this:

```
{sentenceA1}->{sentenceA2,sentenceA3,sentenceA4} or  

{sentenceA2}->{sentenceA1, sentenceA3}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
val lines = List(
  "sentenceA1\tsentenceB1",
  "sentenceA1\tsentenceB2",
  "sentenceA2\tsentenceB1",
  "sentenceA3\tsentenceB1",
  "sentenceA4\tsentenceB2"
)

val afterSplit = lines.map(_.split("\t"))

val ba = afterSplit
  .groupBy(_(1))
  .mapValues(_.map(_(0)))

val ab = afterSplit
  .groupBy(_(0))
  .mapValues(_.map(_(1)))

val result = ab.map { case (a, b) =>
  a -> b.foldLeft(Set[String]())(_ ++ ba(_)).diff(Set(a))
}
```

Comment: I get the error (String, Iterable [String]) does not take parameters 
pointing at ba(_)

Comment: Does this error happen in my code? It's like that your `lines` or other input data has incorrect type - `Iterator` instead of `Seq`. Try debug type of your variables.

Comment: Any ideas on turning them to Seq through scala?

Comment: @Nick Try find out when `Iterator[String]` appears in your code. Maybe you read data from file like `Source.fromFile(filename).getLines()`?

Comment: @Nick Your lines might have `Iterator` type. Excuse me but I can't debug your code instead of you.

Comment: No problem you have been very helpful! I ll try figure out how to convert the data